# Woocommerce "Items in cart" showing as "0 items" need it to display as "0" - need to remove the word "items"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

Site in question: https://www.warehouseappliance.com/

I want to remove the word "items" from the view cart section in header, so it only shows the number.

If one adds a product, the word "item" does get removed, and even if one removes the product from the cart, it will just show a "0". But if I clear cache, it reverts back to the "0 items".

I believe it might be getting added from Javascript at some point. If I check the DOM code, I see "0 items" but if I view the source code I just see the number "0".

Comment: What is your active theme ?

Comment: It's the Woocommerce theme "Homestore" which is a child of "Storefront"

Comment: Made some progress on this. The "items" now is removed after clicking an internal link or refreshing browser. But it's still there for that initial visit.